# Simulating the Lambert W Distribution...

Tags: probability-distributions, simulation, lambert-w

I am trying to simulate the following distribution, with pdf given by:

$$f(t) = \frac{2 \mu  (1-\rho) e^{-2 \mu  t} (1+\mu  \rho  t) \left(\rho ^{K+1} e^{\mu  t}-\rho ^2 \left(e^{\mu  t}-1\right)+\mu  (1-\rho) \rho  t-1\right)}{\left(1-\rho ^{K+1}\right)^2}$$

and cdf

$$F(t)= \frac{(1-\rho) \left(\rho -e^{-\mu  t} (\rho +\mu  \rho  t+1)+1\right)}{1-\rho ^{K+1}},\ \ t >0,\ \rho < 1,\ \ K \gt 0$$.

I am aware that to simulate this, I need to find $F^{-1}(u)$, which is

$$F^{-1}(u) = \frac{\rho  W\left(\frac{e^{-(1+\frac{1}{\rho })} \left(-u \rho ^{K+1}+\rho ^2+u-1\right)}{(1-\rho) \rho }\right)+\rho +1}{\mu  \rho }$$,

which is (I believe) the Lambert-$W$ function.

The question is that I am unclear how to proceed next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I mean't to put $u$ instead of $t$ - I updated the post...

Comment: If you need the real solution,
check the argument $x$
of $\operatorname{W}(x)$:
$x\ge0$-one real solution, $\operatorname{W_0}(x)$;
$-1/e<x<0$-two real solutions, 
$\operatorname{W_0}(x)$ and $\operatorname{W_{-1}}(x)$; 
$x=-1/e$-one real solution, $\operatorname{W_0}(-1/e)=\operatorname{W_{-1}}(-1/e)=-1$;   
$x<-1/e$-no real solutions.